# Sequence of Mobius Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation

Let $ T(z) = \frac {z+2}{2z+1} $. Now it follows that: $ T_1(z) = T(z), T_2(z) = T(T_1(z)), T_3(z)=T(T_2(z)) ....
 T_{n+1}(z)=T(T_n(z)) $ I'm trying to prove this sequence at the nth terms, but I don't see a clear pattern. I know that the $ T(z) =  \frac {az+b}{cz+d} $ and basically it follows that pattern: $ \frac {( \alpha + 1)z+ \alpha}{ \alpha z + ( \alpha  + 1)} $. Please help with proving this sequence. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use induction to show that

$$ T^{(n)}(z) = \frac{a_n + (a_n + (-1)^{n+1}) z}{(a_n + (-1)^{n+1}) + a_n z}$$

where $$a_n = \frac{3^{n+1} + (-1)^n}{2}$$ Note that I have used a convention starting at $n=0$ so $T^{(0)}(z) = T(z)$.

Comment: How did you get the a_n ?

Comment: @silvershew I calculated four terms and saw a pattern: $2,4,14,40,...$ so the next term is roughly $a_{n+1} \approx 3a_n$. Subtracting $a_{n+1}-3a_n$ gave $-2,2,-2,...$ suggesting the equation $a_{n+1} = 3a_n + 2(-1)^n$ which then can be solved with the solution above (using $a_0$=2).

Comment: I see, thanks! The induction step is clear, I was just confused about the beginning part, but it makes sense now.